# PDF Box: extract images from PDF document and keeping the image orientation

Tags: java, image, extract, orientation, pdfbox

I found in this forum some pretty good solutions how to extract images from PDF documents by using PDFBox. I used the following code snipped, that I found in one post:

```
PDPageTree list = document.getPages();
    for (PDPage page : list) {
        PDResources pdResources = page.getResources();
        for (COSName c : pdResources.getXObjectNames()) {
            try {
                PDXObject imageObj = pdResources.getXObject(c);
                if (imageObj instanceof PDImageXObject) {
                    // same image to list
                    BufferedImage bImage = ((PDImageXObject) imageObj).getImage();
                    acceptedImages.add(bImage);
                }
            } catch (MissingImageReaderException mex) {
                log.warn("Missing Image Reader for format: ", mex);
            }
        }
    }
```

But I got the problem, that in rare cases, some extracted images have a wrong orientation. When I look at the PDF document, the pictures are displayed correctl. But some of the extracted images are rotated by n x 90° degrees. I guess the rotation information is stored somewhere in the PDF?

Comment: You could run PrintImageLocations.java and analyse the CTM to extract the rotation with `Math.round(Math.toDegrees(Math.atan2(m.getShearY(), m.getScaleY())))`

Comment: Simply one line... that works fine.  I got headaches on this problem. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Run the `PrintImageLocations.java` example from the source code download (or [here](https://svn.apache.org/viewvc/pdfbox/branches/2.0/examples/src/main/java/org/apache/pdfbox/examples/util/PrintImageLocations.java?view=markup)) and analyse the CTM ("current transformation matrix") to extract the rotation with `Math.round(Math.toDegrees(Math.atan2(ctmNew.getShearY(), ctmNew.getScaleY())))`.

Comment: Hello, I found an example where the PrintImageLocations.java produces the wrong output. The PDF is constructed with Word and I placed within the document three pictures with rotation of 0°, 90°, 180°. The PDFImageLocation calculates the right rotation angels, but the original images are correct and the transformed are not correct. They are rotated by the mentioned angels. I can provide the test PDF and the output of the PDFImageExtractor.

Comment: Please create an issue in the PDFBox JIRA  https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/PDFBOX